# Spring AWS Elastic cache Redis session time out/TTL issue for key PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis-cache, amazon-elasticache

Tools used:

1. springBootVersion = '2.1.3.RELEASE'
2. jdk-11.0.4
3. AWS Elastic Cache -Redis

How do we kill the cache indices created by Spring default session by setting timeout (TTL) or programmatically - By default spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME index is created in Redis with -1 expiry which is infinite in nature and it is eating Cache memory.

I have tried spring.cache.redis.time-to-live but it doesn't work.